# dplyr pass a list of columns to a function to count missing

Tags: r, dplyr

Data:

```
gendata <- data.frame(xcont1=rnorm(n=1000, mean=3, sd=2), xcont2=rnorm(n=1000, mean=3, sd=4))
```

Looking to create a function to count a number of missing and non-missing for a list of columns:

```
create_summary <- function(inputdata, ...) {
  inputvar_quos = quos(...)
  miss_dt <- inputdata %>%
  select(!!!inputvar_quos)  %>%
  summarize_all( list(na=sum(is.na(.)), nonna=sum(!is.na(.)) ))
  return(miss_dt)
}
 
create_summary(gendata, xcont1, xcont2)
```

It throws one of the two errors depending on a package version:

> Error: expecting a one sided formula, a function, or a function name.
>
> Error: Can't create call to non-callable object

At the same time having

```
 summarize_all(list(sum=sum, sd=sd))
```

instead works fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly to do with syntax when passing multiple functions to `summarise_all`

```
library(dplyr)

create_summary <- function(inputdata, ...) {
   inputvar_quos = quos(...)
   miss_dt <- inputdata %>%
       select(!!!inputvar_quos)  %>%
       summarise_all(list(na= ~sum(is.na(.)), nonna= ~sum(!is.na(.)) ))
   return(miss_dt)
}

create_summary(gendata, xcont1, xcont2)

#  xcont1_na xcont2_na xcont1_nonna xcont2_nonna
#1         0         0         1000         1000
```

---

You can also use `summarise_at` here

```
create_summary <- function(inputdata, ...) {
  inputdata %>%
       summarise_at(vars(...), list(na= ~sum(is.na(.)), nonna= ~sum(!is.na(.))))
}

create_summary(gendata, xcont1, xcont2)
```